# How to convert only parts of a string list into integers

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, int

I have a list of lists like:

```
[['c', '2', '3', '4', 'd', '1'], ['e', '14', '16', '18', 'f', '1'], etc.]
```

They all follow the same pattern (one character string, 3 number strings, one character string, one number string). I would like to convert all of the number strings into integers and am having difficulties doing so.

I have tried an exception loop, which doesn't seem to be working (I'm not sure why). 
I know its targeting the sublists as originally I got a value error of int() doesn't recognise base 10 'c' (the first letter in the first element of the sublist.

```py
rows = []
with open(path) as infile:
    for line in infile:
        line = line.strip()
        if not line:
            continue
        try:
            [[int(i) for i in sub] for i in rows for sub in i]
        except ValueError:
            pass
        rows.append(line.split("\t"))
del rows[0]
```

When I print the results with the exception loop in it, it still produces a list of lists as if the exception wasn't there in the first place. 
e.g.

```
[['c', '2', '3', '4', 'd', '1'], ['e', '14', '16', '18', 'f', '1'], etc.]
```

whereas I expect it to be:

```
[['c', 2, 3, 4, 'd', 1], ['e', 14, 16, 18, 'f', 1], etc.]
```

It is a data set analysis, so a requirement for it is to remain in this list of list format (so I can't target just a list using rows.append, as it changes how to split the final data). I was thinking if I can't get this to work, I might experiment with a full list to tuple conversion, with an exception loop for characters and then attempt to convert and split it back into a list of lists. Any help or understanding why this loop isn't working would be very appreciated, or other ways to get this result.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
print([[int(x) if x.isdigit() else x for x in i] for i in rows])
```

Full code:

```
rows = []
with open(path) as infile:
    for line in infile:
        line = line.strip()
        if not line:
            continue
        rows.append(line.split("\t"))
rows = [[int(x) if x.isdigit() else x for x in i] for i in rows]
del rows[0]
```

Comment: Where within the code would this be placed please? I would like to have it encapsulated within the row variable, so I could place the final product within a defined function (eg graph (header, rows) would have a full output)

Comment: @Aisha Added it

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to rely on autodetect, follow your data format:

```
inp = [['c', '2', '3', '4', 'd', '1'], ['e', '14', '16', '18', 'f', '1']]
out = [[c1, int(d1), int(d2), int(d3), c2, int(d4)] for c1, d1, d2, d3, c2, d4 in inp]
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems in your code, both in the same lane:

```
[[int(i) for i in sub] for i in rows for sub in i]
```

first of all, you are using `i` twice, and you might override it's value. Try to replace one of those `i` with a different letter, for example, `j`

```
[[int(j) for j in sub] for i in rows for sub in i]
```

The second problem is that this is a list of comprehension. You are creating a new list, you are not updating any list. You should assign this list to some variable:

```
rows = [[int(j) for j in sub] for i in rows for sub in i]
```

Also, I saw that user U10-Forward added a nice solution. I just wanted to explain why your solution is not working ;)

Comment: Thank you very much, that's extremely helpful to understand what wasn't working!